# WebSocket connection to "wss" sockjs-node failed for CRA and nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

Here's my development setup:

- I create a react project using `create-react-app`, inside docker
- I serve it the usual way using `npm start` in my `docker-compose.yml` file
- Now it's accessible on my localhost, using `http://localhost:3000`
- To simulate server conditions, I seutp nginx and local DNS
- In `/etc/hosts` I add `127.0.0.1  domain.local`
- Using [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) I make locally valid certificates
- In `nginx` I create the configuration file below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.local;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.local;

    ssl_certificate /Temp/Project/Certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /Temp/Project/Key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I go to `https://domain.local` instead of `http://localhost:3000` I lose hot reloading, and I see this error in my console:

> webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.local/sockjs-node' failed:
> ../../Project/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js @ webpackHotDevClient.js:60
> **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:851
> fn @ bootstrap:150
> 1 @ index.js:7
> **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:851
> checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
> webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
> (anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
> webpackHotDevClient.js:76 The development server has disconnected.
> Refresh the page if necessary.

How can I solve this?

Comment: In a server deployment, I wouldn't expect to see the Webpack dev server at all; `npm run build` your application to static files and serve them directly from the Nginx container.

Comment: I'm not on a server @DavidMaze, why did you assume that? I'm on my local computer, developing. The first line says **Here's my development setup**.

Comment: You can use Node without Docker for that?  I was looking at "to simulate server conditions, I set up nginx" bullet point; in that environment you wouldn't have a dev server.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for responding. I know that I can use node directly without docker. But docker is part of our tech stack and we use it everywhere and we don't install node or laravel or django or .net on our local laptops. We only code inside containers.

Comment: @HosseinFallah you solve this ?

Comment: Yeah @RubenMartins, it worked with adding a couple of lines to my Nginx config file. See the answers.

Answer (score 5):

I am using proxy as well. So the question is how to setup your websocket connection in NGinx.

> ... hop-by-hop headers including “Upgrade” and “Connection” are not passed from a client to proxied server, therefore in order for the proxied server to know about the client’s intention to switch a protocol to WebSocket, these headers have to be passed explicitly:

```
location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

---

What they [recommend doing](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) is a bit longer.

I place `localhost:3000` in previous example for you, but I prefer to use separate `upstream` directive so as not to mix upstreams and addresses. So the full example (inside `http` directive) would be:

```
upstream front {
    server localhost:3000;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.local;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.local;

    ssl_certificate /Temp/Project/Certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /Temp/Project/Key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://front;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://front;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Haven't checked your example with cert`s, though.

Comment: Mind, in case you are using Docker (say docker-compose) and NGinx is inside the docker as well, you dont need to expose front port directly and you don't need to use `localhost` at all. You would be using internal hostnames that come from docker-compose, the only exposed port must be the one of the proxy

Comment: > By default, the connection will be closed if the proxied server does not transmit any data within 60 seconds. This timeout can be increased with the proxy_read_timeout directive.