# Vite + react behind reverse proxy gives MIME type error when fetching images

Tags: nginx, http-headers, vite, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to run a Vite+React application behind a reverse proxy. I can reach and run the app successfully through the port temporarily opened in my docker compose network like this `http://localhost:1234/react/home.html`. However, when I access through the intended route via the NGINX docker, `http://localhost/react/index.html`, I get this:

```
Failed to load module script: 
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/png".
```

And yes, when we look at the headers we can see that both requests are dramatically different. Most notably, the successful request has `Sec-Fetch-Dest: image` and the failing one has `Sec-Fetch-Dest: script`, leading to the above error. It's not even the same referer!

[image: Comparison of successful and failed requests]

If I remove the image, the rest works! It's also worth noting that background images coming from the CSS do work.

How can accessing the same HTML page lead to radically different requests? How to fix it?

**Complementary info**

NGINX config excerpt (note that `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` is done elsewhere):

```
    # React dev environment
# Regex to capture the rest of the path. It seems that with the variable in the proxy-pass, the standard rules don't apply.
location ~ ^/react/(.*)$ {
    # Resolver hack so NGINX config won't fail at startup when React is precompiled.
    # We need this since we can run local setup without react
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=60s;
    set $upstream_react boninabox-react;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream_react:1234/react/$1;

    # Enable hot reloading for dev server
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079753/3519951
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    # --- end hot reloading
}
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/react/",
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 1234
  },
  // Embedding into php website
  // See https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html
  build: {
    // generate .vite/manifest.json in outDir
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      // overwrite default .html entry
      input: ['/src/home.jsx', '/src/project.jsx'],
    },
  },
})
```

I get the same error if I access the Vite+React demo, so it doesn't seem to be in the way the images are imported. Thus I spare the react code here.